# How to disable iPad Support when submitting a build to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to disable iPad support for my app store build. My app has had this disabled for all previous submissions, and should not have a problem keeping it disabled, but all of my recent builds, when archived and submitted, still reflect iPad capabilities.

I have disabled iPad in the Supported Destinations
[Supported Destinations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01zTz.png)

I have ensured that [TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugFGO.png) is set to 1 both in the app target

[and the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqYp7.png).

I have also Cleaned my Build Folder

However, when I archive and submit this app, I see the [option for iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD28V.png), unlike I did for my [currently published app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPyhb.png)

I tried to disable iPad, and ensured this to be the case via Supported Destinations and TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY, but I still see this build to be supported on iPad, unlike my previous builds.

Comment: That's fine, just ignore that. as long as you've removed iPad from your supported destinations that's fine.

Comment: When it was removed previously the iPad screenshot options disappeared entirely. I wouldn't mind, but the app store reviewer was able to run the build on iPad. The core issue seems to be that the setting isn't being communicated on some level.

Comment: I see,make sure all ipad orientations and requires full screen are unchecked in your general section.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. 
Requires Full Screen - No. 
Supported Interface Orientations (iPad) - Empty for Release and Debug

Comment: You can ignore the iPad screenshots while your app is in "prepare for submission". They will disappear once your app is approved and released.  All iPhone apps can run on an iPad; They appear in a phone sized window if you don't have explicit iPad support.